# Can't save node when fields are altered with entity_bundle_field_info

Tags: nodes, hooks

I have a node called Program, with a large number of fields and a custom node form. Because of the very complex way we're indexing it for search, I have two fields, award_type and award_goal, which are being rewritten for the Program node only.

The code is as follows:

```
function this_module_entity_bundle_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle, array $base_field_definitions) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node' && $bundle == 'program') {
    $fields = [];
    $fields['award_type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setName('award_type')
      ->setLabel(t('Award Type'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(-1)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setClass(AwardType::class);
    $fields['award_goal'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setName('award_goal')
      ->setLabel(t('Award Goal'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(-1)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setClass(AwardGoal::class);
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

It works for the existing nodes. However, when I try to create a new node, it throws an error:

Drupal\Core\Database\InvalidQueryException: Query condition 'node__field_program.field_program_target_id IN ()' cannot be empty. in Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Condition->condition() (line 105 of /home/admin1/web-projects/miraweb2021/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Query/Condition.php).

Not only that, it won't upload any media to media fields on the node.

Oh, and just for fun, I did not write this code. It was done by a now long-gone consultant.

I can't seem to find anything in the community regarding this issue. Is everything in the hook correct? I have already tried adding a core_entity_field_storage_info; that did nothing.

I'm under a deadline and making zero progress. Has anyone else encountered this? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Welcome. What is the error? Add that to the Question. Also, there isn't a question in this post.

Comment: Reposted according to etiquette. Thanks and my bad.

Comment: Have you gone as far as to get a stack trace?

Comment: It sounds like there's a custom hook firing when you save the node, and it's expecting a value in a field that's not set, though this is only a guess.